# How to add symbols representing point types in y labels

Tags: gnuplot

I want to add the symbols representing point types to y and y2 labels.

Here is the test code:

```
set key center top;
set ylabel "x"; 
set y2label "x^2";
plot x w lp pt 5 pi 5, x**2 w lp pt 7 pi 5 axes x1y2;
```

It gives:

[image]

I want the following:

[image]

Is there anyway to achieve this in Gnuplot?

I am using Gnuplot 4.6.5.

Thanks.

Comment: The only viable way I know of is to use `set label ... point pt 7 lt 2` to place a dot somewhere. But that needs some fiddling around to get the correct position.

Comment: @Christoph Is it possible to use a symbol to express the point type? E.g. Is square a symbol that is included in the symbol list supported in labels in Gnuplot? The symbols I have used are only {Symbol a} etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `set label ... point pt 7 lt 2` to place a dot somewhere. But that needs a lot of tweaking to get the correct position. And that position would need to be adapted manually depending on the font, font size, canvas size etc.

If only the point shape is important, you can use the respective glyph from the [unicode block: geometric shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes). This is also from where I copied the symbols to the script. You must of course also use a font which includes the respective glyphs (e.g. Arial Unicode or DejaVu) and a proper terminal (e.g. pdfcairo, pngcairo, wxt are all fine):

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "DejaVu" size 600,300
set output 'square-circle.png'
set key center top
set encoding utf8
set ylabel "x  {/*0.8 ■}"
set y2label "x^2  {/*0.8 ●}"
plot x w lp pt 5 pi 5, x**2 w lp pt 7 pi 5 axes x1y2;
```

Result with 4.6.5 is:

[image]